# Is it a good idea to sync backups from win server 2008 with Live Mesh

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup, synchronization

I've read at http://haacked.com/archive/2011/11/19/specs-for-haacked-com.aspx that Phil Haack uses MS Live Mesh to synch some backups to his home pc.

Aside from the 2GB single file size limit, is it  good idea to do it on a busy web server?

Comment: I wouldn't accept that for a professional setup no. Regardless of how good Live Mesh might be as a tool for home use, where's its SLA for professional use? Will Microsoft do anything other than point at you and laugh if you ring their support line and tell them your website backups are down because of an issue with Live Mesh#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No

Go for a professional solution. Live Mesh is clearly a personal/home use tool.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a few issues with using Live Mesh:

1. It backs up files, not system state.  So you may not lose X, Y, and Z config files, but you will lose the labor it took you to configure the server into a running state.
2. It's not database aware.  If you're using MSSQL or MySQL or INSERTNAMESQL, it won't do a proper backup of the database.  You risk losing a lot of data that way.
3. Live Mesh (and indeed all online backup applications) require bandwidth.  If you're running a busy webserver, can you afford to lose the bandwidth the backups will require?
4. As mentioned in Rob Moir's comment, there's no SLA.  It's a free product.  If it breaks, if Windows suddenly discontinues it, etc., you're up a creek without a paddle.  My general rule of thumb is - if it's leaving my control, I need to be paying for it and/or have an agreement with the vendor.

Answer (score 0):

Bad idea all around!   Microsoft has had SEVERAL blunders the past couple of years with misplacing and downright losing customer data on their cloud offerings for home users.

Also, they provide ZERO support in the event of a failure of their services.